# Tabulator table memory usage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

I am using a Tabulator table in a vue component and after loading 26500 objects from json(1.8mb) consisted of only id and name and the memory usage is 140mb. Here is basically how I am initializing it:

```
this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
        reactiveData: false,
        virtualDom: true,
        data: [],
        layout: "fitColumns",
        height: "500px",
        maxHeight: "500px",
        addRowPos: "top",
        columns [.....]
 }
```

And this is how I am loading the data:

```
this.tabulator.replaceData(jsonData).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
        });
```

I am not sure if this is normal or not? I can see in the chrome dev tools memory tab that the retained memory consumed is mainly by Row in RowManager, which are Tabulator objects. Also I see that there are 26536 Rows, so should this be like this and if so is there any other way to minimize the memory consumption?

Comment: You possibly want this -> https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/virtual-dom

Comment: Yes I read this, so should I add window and buffer to the tabulator initialization? Because it is said that the virtual-dom works out of the box. I even add it to the initialization - virtualDom: true, is this correct?